# ./waf configure returns 'checking for alsa: not found.'

Tags: 14.04, alsa, ardour

I am trying to install Ardour on my Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and have made sure I had alsa-utils installed and have reinstalled it countless times but no matter how much I do it using ./waf configure in the Ardour directory always returns 'checking for alsa: not found." Then ./waf configure stops operating and I am forced to find other alsa packages that I may be missing. As far as I know I do have alsa installed but why isn't ./waf configure detecting it?

Here is the tutorial I am using: http://ardour.org/building_linux.html
and I am about here:

> Now, the build
>
> ./waf configure
>
> ./waf

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The `alsa-utils` package contains tools like `aplay` and `alsamixer`.

The ALSA library is provided by the package `libasound2`.
However, no ordinary user would actually try to *compile* something, so the files needed for development were moved into the separate `libasound2-dev` package.

Comment: Thank you! I installed the libasound2-dev package and my error stopped :D